# ifstream read: where are extra bytes coming from?

Tags: c++, file-io

I am reading WHOIS record files. The first line of a sample file reads, in the editor: "id:0--0.ga"

In code, I check to verify that the first line starts with "id:" as follows:

```
// given ifstream * fs, 
char id[3];
streampos pos = fs-> tellg();
fs -> read(&id[0],3);
fs -> seekg(pos);

if (// id[3] is "id:" ...
```

However, when I do this (and I am running a debugger; further it is compiled with clang rather than gcc), I get the following result in `id`:

[image: Strange stuff in id char array.]

The characters it read, in addition to an 'i', 'd', and ':' were:

```
\xb87#_?
```

Where the question mark has a stop sign around it.  I am not sure how I could have read anything "extra," seeing as I am only reading three bytes into an array of the proper length...

Further, the if statement evaluates to true.

Could this just be a coding mistake, an error in the debugger, or is something else going on?

Comment: nope - its just that the debugger display the string up til the first null. You need to make id 4 bytes and set id[3] to \0

Comment: @pm100 awesome--thanks.

Comment: @pm100 I see you have a couple upvotes.  ill leave up for a few minutes if someone wants to explain why, and accept the answer.  otherwise, going to delete.

Answer (score 0):

The debugger is assuming that `id` contains a string, which it does not. You should probably just ignore the debugger when looking at things that aren't stored in formats you expect the debugger to understand.

The alternative is to mentally convert the debugger's display into the raw memory contents and then mentally parse the raw memory contents in the correct format. We have some area of memory which, if understood to contain a string  would mean "id:\xb87#_? ..." so that same area of memory, if understood to be an array of only three characters, would be "id:".